Missing data in the SQL Server Agent Job Output to a File
I have below script which would give me the definitions of all the views in one of my DBs.
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE[type] = 'V'
This works real good when I run it as a query in SSMS.
But my goal is to run this via SQL Server Agent as a batch job, and output the result to a file. When I do that, I find that some parts of the text of the definitions are missing in the file.
For example if the query window output is something like below:
CREATE   View [xxx].[vw1]  as  SELECT *    FROM [xxx].[vw2] 
I get something like below:
CREATE   View [xxx].[vw1]  as SELECT *     FR
Any idea what's going wrong here?
This is how my batch job configuration looks like.

I'd expect to have all the output result in the text file without losing anything.

As an aside SELECT * is a terrible idea for a VIEW's definition. You need to ensure you are explicit on your column definitions; otherwise you could easily end up with problems as you add/remove columns to the object(s) the VIEW references.

@ThomA Above is just sample definition just to illustrate the problem.

Is it consistently truncated at around the same number of characters? e.g.: the message in dbo.sysjobhistory is nvarchar(4000). You might have more success if the job were an external PowerShell or Python script calling object_definition() directly rather than relying on the Job Agent's logging features.

@AlwaysLearning I actually looked at that. But I couldn't see it as a constant number of characters. Also, I tried casting to NVARCHAR(MAX). But that didn't work either.

So I tried using PowerShell and sqlcmd to do the job and get the output to a text file. Still, there's some missing text in the file. So I guess SQL Server too internally uses the sqlcmd and it is the real culprit behind this problem?

So I was able to finally put an end to this. The real problem was that the Sql Server could only output a limited number of characters (8192) as text, with SELECT. But there seems to be no such limitation with PRINT. So the solution is;

Use a cursor
Loop through all the rows
PRINT them
Use sqlcmd to output the result to a plain text file

The query should be something like this.
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
FROM sys.objects
WHERE [type] = 'V'

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @sql;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
PRINT REPLACE(@sql, '\n', '\r\n')
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @sql;
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

This has to be in a file, so we can let sqlcmd to use that as input.
